# jqueryui drag element multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

how can set up drag and drop to allow dragging of one element multiple times

i have made something like this  http://jsfiddle.net/28SMv/3/ but after draging an item from red to blue the element loses its "draggability" and i cant drag it once more and more.

adding revert:true to draggable seems to work but then i need to remove helper:'clone' cant use them at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drag an item & release without dropping, it stops being draggable.  I'd remove all droppable stuff from that jsfiddle example, just put a bunch of draggables on the screen & try with that.

One possible solution is to rebind draggables after you're done dragging.  Think:

```
function rebindDraggables() {
    $('...').draggable({
        ...
        stop: function() {
            rebindDraggables();
        }
    })
}
```

I'm not sure why in your examples draggables cease to be draggable after the first time.  The jQuery docs might explain this.

Answer (score 0):

You're duplicating/cloning your elements, so the new one obviously won't be draggable. You could make it draggable, although that's much too much work. Just move the original via `.append()`. Note that when you append an existing object to another element, it will remove the original from its place. That seems to me like what you want to do.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/28SMv/7/

You might want the items to be transferable back into the original div: http://jsfiddle.net/28SMv/8/

Note that I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 there, when you switch over to 1.5 it doesn't work. Not sure if that's a bug, or a feature of jQuery. My guess is that it's a bug of 1.5.

Comment: no i dont want the new element to be draggable i want to drag one element  for example (item 1) to the drop zone multiple times